# How can one get executable file-path for a window which is launched as FlatPak application?

Tags: window, window-manager, executable, flatpak, xprop

I know that

```
xprop | awk '/PID/ {print $3}' | xargs ps
```

and

```
xprop | awk '/COMMAND/ {print $4}' | xargs which
```

work great with GUI applications which are deb-packaged, AppImage'd or Snap'd.

But this method does not give executable file-name for application which is packaged as FlatPak.
See example below:

> ```
> $ flatpak run org.libretro.RetroArch
>
> $ xprop 
> _NET_WM_VISIBLE_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "RetroArch   (as superuser)"
> WM_NAME(STRING) = "RetroArch  "
> _NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 446, 744, 207, 24
> WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW
> XKLAVIER_STATE(INTEGER) = 0, -180379392
> _NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = 
> WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
>       window state: Normal
>       icon window: 0x0
> _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 3, 3, 23, 3
> _NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
> _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
> WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "norbert-UX32A"
> _NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 2
> WM_CLASS(STRING) = "retroarch", "retroarch"
> _NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL) =  Icon (16 x 16):
>                   
>     ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓   
>    ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓  
>    ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓  
>    ▓▓▓ ▓▓▓▓▓ ▓▓▓  
>    ▓ ▓▓ ▓▓▓ ▓▓ ▓  
>    ▓ ▓       ▓ ▓  
>    ▓   ▓   ▓   ▓  
>    ▓           ▓  
>    ▓▓         ▓▓  
>    ▓▓▓ ▓▓▓▓▓ ▓▓▓  
>    ▓▓ ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ ▓▓  
>    ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓  
>    ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓  
>     ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
> ```

So I do not see PID- or COMMAND-related lines in `xprop` output. But of course it is launched:

> ```
> $ flatpak ps
> Instance  PID   Application            Runtime
> 752290322 23857 org.libretro.RetroArch org.kde.Platform
> ```

How can I get PID of window created by FlatPak application while using `xprop`, `wmctrl` or something similar?

Comment: When using `wmctrl -lp`, my Flatpak apps either show a PID of 0 or of another PID completely unrelated to the app; `flatpak ps`, of course, shows the proper PID. I've looked through **/run/user/$your_UID/.flatpak** and couldn't found anything you might be able to use.

Comment: I also tried `xdotool getwindowpid $window_ID`, and got: `window $window_ID has no pid associated with it.` You might be out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, flatpak permissions (sandboxing) do not allow for this AFAICT. Just how much of the system is exposed is configurable to some degree so which flatpak you are talking about might be germaine to the question. There's a great deal of information on this and other flatpak related topics [here.](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/index.html)

One notable section is http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html

One alternative approach to locating the executable file path of a flatpak might be checking the configuration files: Excerpt below.

flatpak can operate in system-wide or per-user mode. The system-wide data is located in $prefix/var/lib/flatpak/, and the per-user data is in $HOME/.local/share/flatpak/.

In addition to the default installation locations, more system-wide installations can be defined via configuration files /etc/flatpak/installations.d/, which must have the .conf extension and typically include the installation path in the form `Path=/location/of/installation`. See [the installation documentation](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-installation) for more information.